# Laravel validation : Error in rule array.*

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation, vue.js

I use vuejs in Laravel and have validation rule in form request like

```
'files' => 'required|array',
'files.*' => 'base64'
```

base64 is a custom validation.

In blade view

```
 <div v-for="error in errors['files']" :key='error.id'>
      @{{ error }}
 </div>
```

It works perfectly but it only show errors of *files*, not *files*.*
how can i display errors of *files*.* in view

Help me!
Thank you so much!

**Updated**: This is what i got in files and files.* (in my project *files* become *Attachment.files*)
 Please click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dDxU.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzv5f.png) to see

Comment: I'm just curious, how did you do to define the custom validation rule? Did you do it in the `AppServiceProvider`?

Comment: Can you show here what are you getting in ```errors['files']``` ?

Comment: @JacopoStanchi: Yes, i did it in the AppServiceProvider. But the problem is not in my custom validation rule.

Comment: @Dev: I'm getting errors of required and array rule only.

Comment: @hayumikuran Yes, but just show here the output you're getting and a sample what you want to display here.

Comment: @Dev: Oh sorry, I updated my question, please check!